# Chapter title overlap with content (arsclassica)

Tags: horizontal-alignment, classicthesis

I am currently writing my thesis using the arsclassica. I have minor problem where the long chapter title will overlap with the content of the chapter. [image: the overlap]

This is part in classicthesis.sty which I think responsible for the design of the chapter title.

```
    \newcommand\formatchapter[1]{% 
\vbox to \ht\strutbox{ 
\setbox0=\hbox{\chapterNumber\thechapter\hspace{10pt}\vline\ } 
\advance\hsize-\wd0 \advance\hsize-10pt\raggedright 
\spacedallcaps{#1}\vss}} 
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang] 
   {\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries\sffamily} 
   {\textcolor{halfgray}{\chapterNumber\thechapter} %change the color for main title
   \hspace{10pt}\vline\ }{10pt} 
{\formatchapter}
```

Comment: *Only use short titles with arsclassica!*

Comment: @Johannes_B out of question. I need a long title.

Comment: It is a known feature that arsclassica only works with short titles. It is a design decision. But the is a duplicate Q/A that shows what to do to use long titles. But honestly, don't use arsclassica.

Comment: @Johannes_B I am too deep into this style so no turning back for now. Is there's any solution for this? Otherwise I probably will add some horizontal space manually